# MathJax notation help for iPython NoteBook

Tags: python, algorithm, ipython, mathjax

Can someone help me to start with using MathJax on iPython Notebook? My page section is available from: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/markomanninen/9984423/Perseus%20Greek%20Isopsephy%20Project.ipynb#Cumulative-reciprocal-sum

and I'd like to know how to use MathJax to add mathematic formula on algorithm mentioned on page. Basicly it is:

1/1*10^(n+1) + 1/1*10^(n+1) + ... + 1/9*10^(n+1) where n = [0,5]

and I don't really have starting point how to formulate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I was looking for and got it from iPython hip chat:

```
$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{5} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{9} \frac{1}{10^{n+1} k}$
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

just put $ sign on both side like you do  in Latex.  $1/1*10^(n+1) + 1/1*10^(n+1) + ... + 1/9*10^(n+1)$. And remember change the cell from 'code' to 'markdown'